# Cant connect to Mysql master/slave using Entityframework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure

I have mysql master slave configuration and i cant connect to it when i specify two ips. I search for connection string and found http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

```
Server=serverAddress1, serverAddress2, serverAddress3;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

So its looks simple but when i specify my two ips i get error "**No such host is known**"

I also found https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_replication_load and tried it but strange thing is that then it much slower. So now i am lost i cant use my replication.

PS. I am not sure if it make sense but i am running that on Azure

Answer (score 0):

You should specify server in specific config section

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
 </configSections>
 <MySQL>
   <Replication>
     <ServerGroups>
      <Group name="MasterSlave">
        <Servers>
          <Server name="master" IsMaster="true" connectionstring=" server=<server>;port=<port>;uid=<user>;password=<password>;"/>
          <Server name="slave" IsMaster="false" connectionstring=" server=<server>;port=<port>;uid=<user>;password=<password>;"/>
        </Servers>
      </Group>
    </ServerGroups>
  </Replication>
</MySQL>
```

Then use following as a connection string:

```
"server=MasterSlave;database=sakila;"
```

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_replication_load

Comment: Will this work with EntityFramework ? meaning if I create a SQLConnection using this connection string, will I be able to call stored procedures that are imported using EF?